# gradle distribution - относительный путь к папке как при отладке, так и при сборке

Tags: java, gradle, distribution

Возможно, заголовок не очень понятен, опишу проблему подробнее.

Требуется настроить build.gradle

Имеется следующая структура проекта:

```
main 
  java
  config
```

и build.gradle (ниже только значимый код из скрипта)

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('config') {
                from 'src/main/config'
            }
         }
     }
}
```

в папке config лежат файлы (ini, logback и т.д.) которые я хочу изменять как в процессе разработки, так и в процессе работы уже с собранным приложением.

Т.е к примеру в коде написано `new FileReader("main.ini")` (main.ini лежит в папке config)

и я хочу, чтобы программа подхватывала параметры по относительному пути во всех трех случаях:

1. gralde run (application plugin)
2. idea - Main - run (обычный run на main классе)
3. gradle distZip - unzip - ./program.sh

Как это сделать максимально корректно?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте в структуре проекта ресурсы, и тяните по YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/my.ini"); При этом никаких танцев с бубном не требуется

Comment: В указанном Вами варианте придется вручную читать файлы конфигураций и устанавливать соответствующие значения переменных, что ИМХО не совсем подходит для ситуаций, например, если используется SpringBoot и другие фреймворки с DI и автомаппингом свойств.